# how to create Database server space report on SQL using Command DIR

Tags: sql-server

I need help to Improve Space Check report for the database Server. This is my code;

```
declare @cmd varchar (max) ='exec xp_cmdshell'' DIR "C:\" '''

declare @vrb_Table table (id int identity , dtl varchar(max))

insert @vrb_Table
exec (@cmd)

select * from @vrb_Table
```

Comment: I need help to Improve Space Check report for the database Server?

Comment: If you ask a specific question, you might get suggestions. But "I need help" doesn't provide any useful information about what sort of help you need. And I suggest you stop thinking that using tsql is an appropriate tool to interrogate the OS resources. Lastly, what does "space check report" mean?